# Orbits of a group as finite copies of the orbits of its subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let us consider an abelian group $G = A \oplus H$, where $A$ is a finite group. Let $G$ and $H$ act on a set $X$ and let us consider the $G$-orbits and $H$-orbits of $X$ respectively.

Is it true that for every $G$-orbit, there are $|A|$ many isomorphic copies of $H$-orbit? Does $A$ have to be cyclic?

(The cardinalities of X and G both need not be finite.)

Comment: What's an isomorphic copy of an $H$-orbit? Do you mean isomorphic as a space with $H$ action?

Comment: This is false even if $G$ is assumed to act faithfully. Let $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $A = \langle (1,2) \rangle$, $H = \langle (1,2)(3,4) \rangle$. Then here are two $G$-orbits and two $H$-orbits.

Comment: Isomorphism here means isomorphism as H-sets.

Answer (score 1):

Since you care about Abelian groups, the following proposition should be helpful, noting that for Abelian groups, transitive and faithful implies transitive and free (proof further down).

**Proposition:** Let $G$ act (wlog) transitively and freely on $X$ (on the left), let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, then $X$ is a disjoint union of $[G:H]$ $H$-orbits, each of which is isomorphic as an $H$-set.

*Proof:* Since the orbits decompose $X$ into disjoint pieces for any group acting on it, $X$ is certainly a disjoint union of $H$-orbits. All we need to prove is that there are $[G:H]$ $H$-orbits, and that they are all isomorphic.

Fix $x\in X$, then since $G$ acts transitively and freely on $X$, $X$ is isomorphic to $G$ as a left $G$-set by the map $G\to X$, $g\mapsto gx$. (The map is surjective by transitivity, and injective by freeness). Then under this isomorphism, $H$-orbits *are* just $Hg$ for $g\in G$. I.e. under the isomorphism, the $H$-orbits *are* the right cosets of $H$. Then the isomorphism from $Hg_1$ to $Hg_2$ is just right multiplication by $g_1^{-1} g_2$, which is certainly left $H$-linear.
This proves our claim.

**Comments:** We can assume transitivity, since we only care about $G$-orbits, so we can restrict our attention to a single $G$-orbit. We can assume faithfulness, because if $G$ does not act faithfully, we can quotient out by the subgroup, $N$, that acts trivially. Let $q$ be the quotient map, then we can apply the result to $q(H)\le G/N$. An example for why this assumption is necessary: consider your original question, now assume $A$ acts trivially, then $G$ and $H$ orbits are the same, so the statement you are asking about is false. Thus we need this assumption to say anything meaningful.

**Comment on edit:** As pointed out in the comments, the prior statement of the proposition was false. Previously I had confused the statement of the proposition and had faithful instead of free, but faithful is too weak of an assumption in general, so I've fixed it to what I'm fairly confident is now correct.

*Lemma:* When $G$ is abelian, if $G$ acts transitively and faithfully on $X$, then it acts freely on $X$.

*Proof:* Suppose $gx=x$, then by transitivity for all $y\in X$, there is some $h_y\in G$ such that $h_yx=y$. Then $gy=gh_yx=h_ygx=h_yx=y$ for all $y\in G$, but $G$ acts faithfully, so $g$ must be the identity element. Thus if $gx=x$, $g$ is the identity. This is what is means for $G$ to act freely.

**Edit in response to update that was posted as an answer:**

First of all, I assume you mean $\oplus$ rather than $\otimes$. Then in the case you've given, the situation is the following: We have $R$ a ring, such that $H\subseteq G\subseteq R^\times$. Even if $R^\times$ and $G$ are not commutative, if $gu=u$ for $g\in G$, $u\in U$, we can cancel $u$ to get $g=1$. Thus $G$ acts freely on $R^\times$, so when we restrict to $G$-orbits, $G$ acts transitively and freely on $G$-orbits. Thus we can directly apply the proposition to get that $G$-orbits can be decomposed into $[G:H]$ $H$-orbits each isomorphic as $H$-sets.

Comment: You are assuming in your proposition that $G$ is an abelian group. Also the answer to the question is no even if $G$ is assumed to act faithfully.

Comment: @DerekHolt, sorry it's late where I am, and I can't see where I made that assumption. Can you point out my error more specifically?

Comment: Also I made the assumption that $G$ acts transitively as well, which is important. Your cx above is fixed by restricting to $G$-orbits as I suggest in my answer.

Comment: Actually I see my error, I'll edit later

Comment: The statement that a faithful transitive action is equivalent to the left regular action is true for abelian groups (and for a few other groups such as $Q_8$) but not in general.

Comment: @DerekHolt Right, that was careless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very specific example: Let us consider a multiplicative group $G = U_n \times H$, where $U_n$ is the cyclic group containing $n^{th}$ roots of unity. Let us consider a ring $R$ containing $G$ as a set. Let $G$ act on $R$ by multiplication.

We have, for every $g \in G$, $g = \omega h$ where $\omega \in U_n$ and $h \in H$. So, for each $x \in R$, the $G$-orbit of $x$ corresponds to the following $H$-orbits:

$xH$, $x\omega H$, ... , $x\omega^{n-1}H$

and each of these $H$-orbits are isomorphic under the multiplication map $x \mapsto x \omega$.